# How to install Tikz-cd on MikTex

Tags: packages, tikz-cd

I have to use tikz-cd package to draw triangular commutative diagram. I have downloaded the tikz-cd package and put the file.sty in the same folder where I have the latex file. Then I wrote \usepackage{tikz-cd} but it returns me "Process crashed". Can someone help me? I'm not so able to install Latex packages. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should install it via MiKTeX console (Package Manager).

Comment: Please can you explain me how to do this?

Comment: or can you tell me where can I read about it? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have  a user-installation or an installation for all users?

Comment: Sorr, I don't know. Where can I find this information?

Comment: When you installed MiKTeX, you were asked. Anyway, this is because there is a Package Manager for users, and another as Administrator. The latter is for a system-wide installation. B.t.w. are you under Windows?

Comment: A friend installed MiKtex for me 4 or 5 years ago, this is why I don't know. Yes, I'm using Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do it: in Program Files, select `MiKTeX 2.9 > Maintenance (Admin) > MiKTeX Package Manager`. You should obtain a popup window like this:

[image]

In the small edit window which ends with the icon of a funnel, you can filter the packages to speed up the process. Select the tikz-cd package, right click on it and ask for `install`. That's all.

Comment: I don't have Maintenance, but I have Package manager and Package Manager (Admin). If I open te Admin One, search the package tikz-cd and try to install, Windows says that Miktex stopped working

Comment: Are you sure you you don't have a compilation that's going on?

Comment: Yes, all compilation were closed. Do you know other packages to draw triangular commutative diagrams? I gave up with the installation of tikz-cd :)

Comment: I've uninstalled and then reinstalled Miktex and followed your instructions, now all works! Thanks for your help!